# Why do I need 'class' constraint here

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

Given the following example, I get the following compiler error:
 `Cannot apply operator '==' to type 'TEnumerable' and 'TEnumerable'`

```
class MyClass<TEnumerable, TItem> where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<TItem>
{
  public void DoSomething(TEnumerable item)
  {
    if (item == default(TEnumerable)) return; // Compiler error here
  }
}
```

When I add the `class` constraint

```
class MyClass<TEnumerable, TItem> where TEnumerable : class, IEnumerable<TItem>
```

it compiles as expected. 
According to MSDN, the `class` constraint means:

> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any
>   class, interface, delegate, or array type.

But `IEnumerable<TItem>` is already a `reference type` (all interfaces are reference types), so the `class` constraint adds no further restriction. So my question is: Why do I need this constraint at all?

Comment: `struct`s can implement interfaces just as well as `class`es can.

Comment: As an example, you could make (in .NET 4.5 (2012) or later) a `var mc = new MyClass<ArraySegment<string>, string>();`. This shows that your `TEnumerable` can be a value type. If you include the `: class` contraint, that possibility is no longer present.

Comment: Good example. Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Without the `class` constraint you could have written `if (EqualityComparer<TEnumerable>.Default.Equals(item, default(TEnumerable))) return;`.